# how to change datetime format in pandas. fastest way?

Tags: python, pandas

I import from .csv and get object-type columns:

```
    begin                           end
0   2019-03-29 17:02:32.838469+00   2019-04-13 17:32:19.134874+00
1   2019-06-13 19:22:19.331201+00   2019-06-13 19:51:21.987534+00
2   2019-03-27 06:56:51.138795+00   2019-03-27 06:56:54.834751+00
3   2019-05-28 11:09:29.320478+00   2019-05-29 06:47:21.794092+00
4   2019-03-24 07:03:03.582679+00   2019-03-24 09:50:32.595199+00
```

I need to get in datetime format:

```
    begin       end
0   2019-03-29  2019-04-13
1   2019-06-13  2019-06-13
2   2019-03-27  2019-03-27
3   2019-05-28  2019-05-29
4   2019-03-24  2019-03-24
```

what I do (at first I make them datetime format, then cut to dates only, then make datetime format again):

```
df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], dayfirst=False)
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], dayfirst=False)

df['begin'] = df['begin'].dt.date
df['end'] = df['end'].dt.date

df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], dayfirst=False)
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], dayfirst=False)
```

Is there any short way to do this without converting 2 times?

Comment: You can do it in one line: `df["begin"] = pd.to_datetime(df["begin"]).dt.date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` on the 2 columns, each with `pd.to_datetime` once and use [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to remove time info, yet maintaining as `datetime` format. (Also used [`dt.tz_localize(None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) to remove timezone info):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.tz_localize(None).dt.normalize())
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

        begin         end
0  2019-03-29  2019-04-13
1  2019-06-13  2019-06-13
2  2019-03-27  2019-03-27
3  2019-05-28  2019-05-29
4  2019-03-24  2019-03-24


df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   begin   5 non-null      datetime64[ns]          <=== datetime format
 1   end     5 non-null      datetime64[ns]          <=== datetime format
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```